# HTML content beneath the fixed navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how do i put my content just beneath my navigation. Every time i put some text inside the   it just goes behind the green background and gets covered up by the navigation. Please kindly help me how to put my text beneath the navigation

```html
<html>
<style>

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1E9600;
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 height:75px;
}


li {
    float: left;
 height:75px;
 border-right: 5px solid red;
}
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>e>


</style>
<head>
<title> E-Benta </title>

<ul>
<li><a href="Home.html"> <img src="logo.png"> </img> </a>
<li><a href ="Home.html">Home </a></li>
<li><a href ="Products.html">Products </a>
<li><a href ="about.html">About us </a>
<li><a href ="contact.html">Contact us </a>
</ul>
</head>
<spacer>testing </spacer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add to your  this code:

```
spacer {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 75px;
}
```

Everything will be ok. Just add margin-top bigger than height of fixed menu.

Check snippet here: http://codepen.io/Dzongkha/pen/PbbvLZ

Comment: thanks bro, anyways, what should you think about the content that I should put on my homepage?

Comment: Sorry, I can't advise you about content on your page, but I hope that my answer helps you to resolve your issue =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave space at top (as much as header). You can use margin top for that.

inline code would be

```
<spacer style="margin-top:90px;float: left;">testing </spacer>
```

You can create class for that and assign to spacer as well.

```html
<html>
<style>

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1E9600;
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 height:75px;
}


li {
    float: left;
 height:75px;
 border-right: 5px solid red;
}
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>e>


</style>
<head>
<title> E-Benta </title>

<ul>
<li><a href="Home.html"> <img src="logo.png"> </img> </a>
<li><a href ="Home.html">Home </a></li>
<li><a href ="Products.html">Products </a>
<li><a href ="about.html">About us </a>
<li><a href ="contact.html">Contact us </a>
</ul>
</head>
<spacer style="margin-top:90px;float: left;">testing </spacer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i seen here your code html structure is not proper, It should be like

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>

        <!-- YOUR CSS <style> or <link> tag GOES HERE -->

     </head>
     <body>

        <!-- YOUR CONTENT ELEMENT SHOULD BE HERE -->

    </body>
</html>`
```

```css
body{
margin-top:60px; /* IF Navigation is fixed top you have to put margin top to body as header hight */
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 5px solid #ddd;
  }
  li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 22px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#333;
  }
  .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }

/*MAIN CONTENT CSS HERE*/
.main-content-here{
  padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="Home.html"><img src="logo.png" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="Home.html">Home </a></li>
  <li><a href="Products.html">Products </a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About us </a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us </a></li>
</ul>
<div class="main-content-here">
  <spacer>testing</spacer>
</div>
```

AND last

**Practice make perfect!!!! :)**